# How to show the following equality for the matrices?

Tags: matrices, systems-of-equations, matrix-equations

I have following matrices whose entries can be complex values $$\mathbf{H^{12},H^{21},H^{23},H^{32},H^{31},H^{13},V^1,V^2,V^3}.$$ All the $\mathbf{H^{ij}}$ matrices are full rank, all have same size and are diagonal. If $$\mathbf{H^{12}V^2=H^{13}V^3}~~~~~~~~~(1)\\\mathbf{H^{23}V^3\prec H^{21}V^1}~~~~~~~~~(2)\\ \mathbf{H^{32}V^2\prec H^{31}V^1}~~~~~~~~~~(3)$$ (please note that the dimensions of matrices are chosen in such a way that the above matrix multiplications are possible) then how to show that $$\mathbf{H^{12}(H^{21})^{-1}H^{23}(H^{32})^{-1}H^{31}(H^{13})^{-1}(H^{31})^{-1}H^{32}V^2}=\mathbf{(H^{21})^{-1}H^{23}V^3}~~~~~~(4)$$ Any help in this regard will be much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

My attempt:

I tried to get equation $(4)$ by multiplying both sides of $(1)$ by $\mathbf{(H^{21})^{-1}H^{23}(H^{13})^{-1}}$ but then I get $$\mathbf{(H^{21})^{-1}H^{23}(H^{13})^{-1}H^{12}V^2}=\mathbf{(H^{21})^{-1}H^{23}V^3}$$ although the right sides are equal but we can see that left sides are not equal. Therefore, I need help in showing the above relation.

Comment: What does $\prec$ mean?

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa According to the research paper that I am reading the definition is as follows. If $\mathbf{P\prec Q}$ then it means that the set of column vectors of matrix $\mathbf{P}$ is a subset of the set of column vectors of matrix $\mathbf{Q}$. But as you may know that in the context of convex optimization $\mathbf{0}\prec \mathbf{Q-P}$ also means that $\mathbf{Q-P}$ is positive definite. I am not sure if these definitions means the same thing. Please tell if they mean the same thing. Thank you. BTW I already found how the equality can be proved and it has nothing to ....

Comment: @GonzaloAlejandroBenavidesGa ... do with $\prec$ sign since it relies on the assumption that all $\mathbf{H^{ij}}$ are diagonal matrices of same size.